# Watir Rails - Table with Buttons click on one near specific Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, watir

I'm using Watir and Phantomjs to manage customer settings on a self-care portal.

I'm dealing with a table with a single Column and several rows in which it show a list of available package that can be subscribed. On each row I can find the description and a button. Each button has it own ID generated by the page but all of buttons has same description. 
Pasting the formatted HTML I found that

```
+-----------------------------------+
|       Available Packages          |
+-----------------------------------+
| Package_1             [subscribe] |
| Package_2             [subscribe] |
| Package_3             [subscribe] |
| Package_4             [subscribe] |
| Package_5             [subscribe] |
```

I'm trying to click on the button for a specific row that contain a text but unsuccessfully. I can't even select the row...How can I do that?

```
browser.td(:text => /^Package_2/)
```

return

```
 => #<Watir::TableDataCell:0x..fc0259e6592e39a6 located=false selector={:text=>/^Package_2/, :tag_name=>"td"}>
```

The HTML Table is generated on loading page. An example with two packages is:

```
<table id="j_id174" class="scrollTable4" width="820px">
   <thead class="fixedHeader4 headerFormat4">
      <tr>
         <td style="background:none"></td>
         <td width="100%"></td>
      </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody class="scrollContent4 bodyFormat4">

      <tr id="showdivj_id1740" style="background-color:#e0e0e0;">
         <td style="background-color:#ffffff;background-image:none;"><a href="javascript:DivStatus( 'mondiv','j_id174',0)" style="text-decoration:none;"><img id="imgj_id1740" border="0" src="../imgs/puce_plus.png" width="13" height="13"></a></td>
         <td>
            <div style="position:relative;"><span class="xdt">PACKAGE_1</span><button type="button" onclick="return _chain('blockpage()','submitForm(\\'j_id13\\',0,{source:\\'j_id174:0:j_id180\\'});return false;',this,event,true)" class="xe4 x7i">subscribe</button></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="showdivj_id1741" style="background-color:#e0e0e0;">
         <td style="background-color:#ffffff;background-image:none;"><a href="javascript:DivStatus( 'mondiv','j_id174',1)" style="text-decoration:none;"><img id="imgj_id1741" border="0" src="../imgs/puce_plus.png" width="13" height="13"></a></td>
         <td>
            <div style="position:relative;"><span class="xdt">PACKAGE_2</span><button type="button" onclick="return _chain('blockpage()','submitForm(\\'j_id13\\',0,{source:\\'j_id174:1:j_id180\\'});return false;',this,event,true)" class="xe4 x7i">subscribe</button></div>
         </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: So does at least a click on any line work? Please [edit] your question to clarify it further and add the markup of the table. You will probably need to use XPath expressions or move from one element to the next in the DOM. Either way, we need to see the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button to be clicked is in the same cell as the text being matched. You have already retrieved the `td` element with matching text, so you simply need to click the one button within it:

```
browser.td(:text => /^Package_2/).button.click
```